# Create CRUD Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have split my mvc4 application in two projects. One main and one Model which is referenced in main project.  However when I try to create a CRUD controller I get an exception in `ControllerWithContext.tt(-1,-1)` ,

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assebmly .... or one of
>   its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified.

What is wrong?

Comment: Could you possibly add more code and exactly how you are referencing your file? it seems like the way you have it set up there is something either missing or incorrectly setup. Also is it necesary to split the model entirely out of the project. MVC Areas could work nicely for this, and not require any issues of referencing.

Comment: does you model assembly contains POCO entities.Are you using any auto code generation strategy?

Comment: I am using EF code first approach with plain POCO for my model, which resides in ModelProject. In my main mvc 4 Project I added the reference to the Model Project, nothing more.

Comment: Wild guess here: if you are generating the controller using the Visual Studio wizard, make sure you have built the solution at least once or it will not be able to find the relevant classes...

Comment: I have bult, rebuilt the project and the Controler wizard find the necessary classes just fine. However while the process starts it throws the above error. Also, when I put my models in the Main project it generates the controller without problems.

Comment: Try restarting your visual studio,clean up your solution and do a rebuild.see if that solves your problem

Comment: Same result,after restarting visual studio and cleaning up solution

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from the EF connection string. Usually, when you want to use an embedded resource, you should set the `Metadata` in the EF ConStr like the following:

```
Metadata=res://<assemblyFullName>/<resourceName>.
```

You also can use the `*` wildcard instead of `<assemblyFullName>` like the following:

```
Metadata=res://*/model.csdl| ...
```

Where `model` is the name of youe .EDMX file. It causes the EF to search the following locations for the file at runtime:

- The calling assembly.
- The referenced assemblies.
- The assemblies in the bin directory of an application.

If you are trying to get a model from another project, you should enter the full name of your project in the metadata:

```
Metadata=res://MyModelPrj/model.csdl | ...
```

Finally, if your solution contains just a .EDMX file, you can simply use the following:

```
Metadata=res://*/
```

Note that this works only if you have only one model in the whole solution. If you have more than one model in your solution, It just cause another error...!

More info is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cc716756.aspx)